# Border radius 50% on parent doesn't round corners

Tags: html, css, less

I have an anchor tag that has `border-radius: 50%` on it with a fixed width and height. The child element is an image tag that has a fixed height of 30px but `width: auto` because the dynamic image source will always be a landscape image so it will have a larger width than 30px.

The problem that I am having is even though the anchor tag has `border-radius: 50%` and `overflow: hidden` the image is still appearing outside of the container.

I've tried adding `opacity: 0.99` and `background-color: #FFFFFF` to the anchor tag but all that does is make the image sit behind the background-color. I've tried setting a z-index on it and it does absolutely nothing.

Does anyone have a solution to this? If it helps, I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.2 on the site.

```
.name {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.profile-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -30px;
    right: -30px;
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

<a href="/" class="name">
    <img src="imageSource" class="profile-img">
</a>
```

Comment: It may not look like you want it to look, but the image is [definitely not outside its container](https://jsfiddle.net/58e8ce6k/2/). Please clarify: What's the intended behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found an answer to this that is quite dirty, but is working for what I need it for...

The original issue seemed to only affect mobile devices, specifically Android Chrome. For some reason, the image would hide itself in the browser if the image was smaller than 60 pixels, not sure how or why this happens but my work around is below:

```
.profile-img__wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #d0d0d0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.profile-img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    background-position: 50% 0; 
}

<span class="profile-img__wrapper">
    <span class="profile-img" style="background-image: url('imageSource')"></span>
</span>
```

Using the above code allows the background image to keep its image ratio and center it in the element that it's sitting on.

Answer (score 0):

find the below code works fine.

```css
.name {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    border : 1px solid black;
}

.profile-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -30px;
    right: -30px;
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="name">
  <img src="http://justvidit.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/yellow-orange-summer-sun-light-burst-1.jpg" class="profile-img">
</a>
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @Roy let me know what exactly you are looking

Comment: I'm not the one with the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
<a href="/" class="name">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="profile-img">
</a>

.name {
     position: relative;
     border-radius: 50%;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     display: inline-block;
     border: 1px solid #000;
 }

 .profile-img {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: -30px;
     right: -30px;
     width: auto;
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

well its works fine to me

But if you want to make your background transparent use rgba value